# Need help splitting a string

Tags: javascript, split

I have the following string:

```
(42332,4333),(3243242,23432)
```

And I want to use a regex to produce the following:

```
[0]=42332,4333
[1]=3243242,23432
```

Comment: You want to do it - nothing hinders you - do it. Where is your problem?

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far - otherwise you could just be asking us to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
var s = "(42332,4333),(3243242,23432)"

s.match(/(\d+\,\d+)/g); // return ["42332,4333" , "3243242,23432"]
```

Comment: Thanks but i think this will only remove the round bracktes

Comment: @CBM this code will return an array with both the values, as you asked.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a regular expression, as a string.split will not really work in this situation.

```
var yourString = '(42332,4333),(3243242,23432)';

var result = yourString.match(/\((\d+,\d+)\)/g);

result[0]; // '42332,4333'
result[1]; // '3243242,23432'
```

You can mess around with the regex here: http://regexr.com?31n05

Comment: Hey thanks ..but one small issue is if the numbers are floating numbers then the array returns null

Comment: @CBM because the regular expression does not allow `.`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`("(42332,4333),(3243242,23432)").replace(/(\),\()|(\)|\()/g, '$1').split('),(')`

Comment: Thanks a lot ..exactly what i wanted